# Locally integrable function with a uniform bound...

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

I'm a bit lost...  I have a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B}(\Omega),\mu)$  where $\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$ is a Borel set. Let $f$ be a real-valued measurable function on $\Omega$ and $\mathcal{K}$ be the set of all compact sets in $\Omega$. If
$$
\sup_{K\in\mathcal{K}}\int_K \lvert f(x) \rvert\, \mu(dx) < +\infty\,, 
$$

do we have $f\in L^1(\Omega,\mu)$?

We can add any nice property on $\Omega$ like locally compact, or $\mu$ being $\sigma$-finite, etc. Thanks in advance... Maybe a hint because it is not clear at  all for me.

Sincerely.

Comment: I'm not certain but I think you may need inner regularity on $\mu$.

Comment: I agree, if it is true a good start should be $\Omega$  separated and $\mu$ inner regular.

Comment: The truth is, I don't know if it is true with $\Omega = \mathbb R$ and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure...

Comment: @Airlast It is true for Lebesgue measure, as a result of (e.g.) Monotone Convergence, for positive $f$. The functions $f \chi_{[-N, N]}$ converge to $f$ pointwise, and $\int f \chi_{[-N,N]} \to \int f$. Then split into real / imaginary and positive / negative parts.

Comment: Of course, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It suffices to know that there is a sequence of compact sets $K_n$ that satisfies $\mu(\Omega \setminus \bigcup K_n) = 0$ (why!? Use monotone convergence and the fact that the $K_n$ can be taken to be an increasing sequence).

The above is fulfilled e.g. if

1) $\Omega$ is $\sigma$-compact, or

2) $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite and inner regular, because then $\Omega = \bigcup M_n$ with an increasing sequence $M_n$ each of finite measure, so that for every $n$ there exists a compact $K_n$ with $\mu(M_n \setminus K_n) < 2^{-n}$, so that

$$
\mu (\Omega \setminus \bigcup K_n) = \lim_m \mu(M_m \setminus K_n) \leq \lim_m 2^{-m} = 0. 
$$

Comment: Good answer. Beat me to it as I wrote my answer up. (+1)

Comment: Excellent, many thanks!